# How to delete related schema in mongodb using node js (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to delete my 2nd schema which having reference in first schema

ownerSchema.js

```
var ownerSchema = Schema({
    ownerId   : String,
    fname     : String,
    lname     : String,
    shopPlace : { 
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: 'Shop'
                }
});
var Owner = mongoose.model('Owner', ownerSchema);
```

shopSchema.js

```
var shopSchema = Schema({
    _id       : String,
    shopName  : String,
    location  : String,
    startDate : Date,
    endDate   : Date
});
var Shop  = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

so I am trying to delete my 2nd schema but it only deleting 1st schema

```
const Owner = require("../models/ownerSchema");
const Shop = require("../models/shopSchema");

const deleteOnwerById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  let deletedShop = await Shop.deleteOne({_id:shopPlace}); // I can't delete my shop data
  let deletedTask = await Owner.deleteOne({ ownerId: id });
  } // I can delete owner but not shop detail
};
```

but it not deleting my related schema

Comment: Well yeah, the `Owner` schema has no `ownerId` field. You are trying to `deleteOne({ ownerId: id })`, necessarily, no document will match.

Comment: actually `ownerSchema` has its own id its `_id` which come by default and i added my `ownerId` as well here @JeremyThille

Comment: where does `shopPlace` come from?

Comment: Yes, you added it after my first comment :)

Comment: from ownerSchema @NikitaMazur

Comment: but in your example its `undefined`

Comment: ya that's why I want to know how can i delete my shop schema data too  or what parameter should i pass to delete my shop data if owner data is deleted @NikitaMazur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, delete your Owner using [findByIdAndRemove](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) or [findOneAndDelete](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete). These methods allow you to specify one or several fields to return from the deleted documents by passing it an optional `options` object.

```
let deletedOwner = await Owner.findByIdAndRemove(ownerId, {projection : "shopPlace"});
```

Then use the owner's shopPlace to delete the corresponding shopPlace :

```
await Shop.deleteOne({_id:deletedOwner.shopPlace});
```

Comment: If i want to delete by _id show how will i give Or condition here ?

Comment: as I have `ownerId` which is given by me but even mongodb also give its default `_id` so should i use `{_id : id || ownerid : id}` or how ?

Comment: Ah, you can use `{ $or : [ {_id:id} , {ownerId:id} ]}`

Comment: its showing `Can't use $or` @jeremy

Comment: What's "it"? What's the code? Also, this is another question, you should ask it separately on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You must first get an _id from `shopPlace` of your owner:

```js
const Owner = require("../models/ownerSchema");
const Shop = require("../models/shopSchema");

const deleteOnwerById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const owner = await Owner.findOne({ ownerId: id }).populate('shopPlace');
  let deletedShop = await Shop.deleteOne({ _id:owner.shopPlace._id });
  let deletedTask = await Owner.deleteOne({ ownerId: id });
  }
};
```

Comment: Simply deleting the Owner first will return the deleted document. It contains the `shopPlace._id`; you don't need to query for it first, even less populating it

Comment: I just considered, he wants to remove shop first)

Comment: But why? There's no reason for wanting to delete one before the other. Even then, there's no need to populate

Comment: Yeah and btw, deleteOne doesnt return a document

Comment: Ah crap, you're right, I mixed up with the native [findOneAndDelete](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/) which does :/

Comment: I have updated my answer. `deleteOne` does not return the document, but `findByIdAndRemove` and `findOneAndDelete` do. These are basically find + delete in one operation.

Comment: @JeremyThille good job)